# Map from HttpPostedFileBase to Byte[] with automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

Im trying to upload a picture and use automapper to convert it from HttpPostedFileBase to Byte[]. This is my CreateMap:

```
            Mapper.CreateMap<HttpPostedFileBase, Byte[]>()
            .ForMember(d => d, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => 
                {
                    MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                    s.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                    return target.ToArray();
                }));
```

I get an error on s : A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.

So how should i write my CreateMap to get this to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do this:

1. Use a [custom type converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters):

   ```
   public class HttpPostedFileBaseTypeConverter : 
       ITypeConverter<HttpPostedFileBase, byte[]>
   {
       public byte[] Convert(ResolutionContext ctx)
       {
           var fileBase = (HttpPostedFileBase)ctx.SourceValue;

           MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
           fileBase.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
           return target.ToArray();        
       }
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   Mapper.CreateMap<HttpPostedFileBase, byte[]>()
       .ConvertUsing<HttpPostedFileBaseTypeConverter>();
   ```
2. Use `ConstructUsing` and do it inline:

   ```
   Mapper.CreateMap<HttpPostedFileBase, byte[]>()
       .ConstructUsing(fb =>
   {
       MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
       fb.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
       return target.ToArray();
   });
   ```

Comment: in case anyone is using this with AutoMapper v6 and later, the Convert arguments would look like this:
`Convert(HttpPostedFileBase source, byte[] destination, ResolutionContext ctx)`
and we would use `source` instead of `ctx.SourceValue`

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best way to read bytes from a file upload because IIS allocates the entire size of the uploading file when the uploading process starts. Then your mapper allocates another similar size of bytes (byte[] array is a new variable) and the overall memory usage is going to be file bytes * 2.

My advice is to read the posted file stream and to write it somewhere. You can do any post-upload processing after uploading.

Comment: I see your point, but don't completly understand how to do it. Can you post some example code?

Comment: You can use FileStream instead of MemoryStream or you can use SaveAs method easily. If there is no processing like a resizing, encoding etc, then do it when upload finished. If there is no processing on uploading file then avoid map or reuse or copy stream/data to another variable.